# How to add white space at end of grid rows without stretching items

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to layout a container div to fill the size of the screen but I want the empty rows to be at minimum width, e.g. 40px, and just have empty space after the last row. But the content stretches and I don't know why.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(40px, auto);
  background: red;
}

.test{
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 350px;
}

.content-after-grid{
  margin: 0;
  background-color:black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cms-static.wehaacdn.com/hoards-com/images/milk.16566.jpg" class="test">
</div>
<div class="content-after-grid">
</div>
```

The image in the snippet is supposed to be `40px` from the top and the remaining space should be empty. More or less it should work like `auto-fill`. How do I go about achieving this?

Edit: I've added an image to show what I'm trying to do in more detail. I also added a block after the grid to show what's happening so far. The image should be in a row that shares its height. That is why I use `minmax()`. Because I want empty rows to to have a height of `40px` but rows with content expand to fit that content hence the `minmax(40px, auto)`. It should be working like `auto-fill` would be for `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns`

[image: Target Layout]

Comment: `min-max` --> `minmax`

Comment: Edited and thank you for pointing that out. Just for clarity's sake that wasn't the issue and was just cleaning up the question.

Comment: you should just give the image a margin-top:40px and that should do the trick. then set the height of the image to "height: calc(100vh - 40px)". I'm not sure I understand the question correctly so let me know if this misses the mark

Comment: @Deeswoc not 100% sure what you mean bro. Can you draw the layout that you want to achieve on Paint or something? If you wonder why the image stretches, I might guess that because you didn't explicitly assign `height: 100%` for it, so its height was different than the height of row it's sitting on.

Comment: @Loi Nguyen Huynh The layout has been added. The image itself doesn't stretch. The row does. I made an error in writing and said `auto-fit` instead of `auto-fill` so it there may have been confusion.

Comment: @Digglit That's not what I want. I want to add rows of content and for the div to push the footer down to the bottom of the page if the content doesn't take up enough space. I'd be using empty rows for spacing which is why i have the `minmax(40px, auto)`. The behavior I'm looking for is that the first row should be 40px and the image is inserted in the second row. The second row should expand and wrap the image taking up the same height as said image. Then like in `grid-template-rows` or `grid-template-columns` it should have a behavior like `auto-fill` and leave the rest of the div empty.

Comment: @Deeswoc I've added a snippet below according to the image you give, give it a look to see if it's what you want. If it is, you might have had the problem that is overcomplicate the problem. All I do below is `grid-template-rows: 40px auto 1fr;`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? What you need is `grid-template-rows: 40px auto 1fr;`: *the first row takes 40px, and the last row takes all the remaining space*

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 40px auto 1fr;
  background: red;
}

.test{
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 350px;
}

.content-after-grid{
  margin: 0;
  background-color:black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cms-static.wehaacdn.com/hoards-com/images/milk.16566.jpg" class="test">
</div>
<div class="content-after-grid">
</div>
```

Comment: Nguyen Haynh It looks like the layout i want but It isn't what I'm looking for. The number of rows shouldn't be explicitly stated. If you were to add an image to row 3 it would break the layout. When you add an image to a row lower in the document it should automatically have rows in between be 40px and the bottom leave the space empty after the row the last image was inserted into.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give the non-working code and the images describe what you would expect? In this case, you could try wrapping the second row inside another container, a `grid` inside a `grid`.